# Why "Go Out and Learn"

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, lavan

Why does the Haggada say **צֵא** וּלְמַד מַה בִּקֵּשׁ לָבָן הָאֲרַמִּי לַעֲשׂוֹת לְיַעֲקֹב אָבִינוּ - **Go out** and see what Lavan tried to do" Why not just learn it or hear it rather than "go out and see"?

**Note:** If you will say seeing makes a bigger impact than hearing, why don't we say about everything in the Haggada, "Go out and see"?

Comment: Interesting Ta shma or ta chaze is come in and learn

Answer (score 4):

From [Oz V’hadar’s extended Mesivta Haggadah](http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/department/63/pesach), pages 528-529:

- **Rashba”tz**: The expression is a general expression meaning to begin expounding. Compare the similar expressions צא ולמד משוק של חמורים in Chagigah 9b and מכאן ואילך צא וחשוב in Avodah Zarah 9a.
- **Abarbanel**: “Go out” from the topic of Pesach “and learn” about Lavan.
- **Midrash Aggadah**: The expression is a general expression for when you’re discussing one subject and must “go out” from that subject “and learn” something else which is relevant. Compare the similar expression צא ולמד ממה שאמור בענין in Kiddushin 37a.
- **Iyun Tefillah**: The phrase צא ולמד should be pronounced “tzei u’lemeid,” rather than “tzei u’lemad.” The idea is that one should seek out to *teach* his children about what Lavan did.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you please explain why so that I can improve this?